# Error recognizing character inside character literal in ANTLR4

Tags: regex, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

I need to recognize a "character literal" in my lexical analyzer, however I am having some problems.

The lexical analyzer specification is as follows:

```
lexer grammar LexerRules;

INT             :   'Int';
FLOAT           :   'Float';
STRING          :   'String';
BOOL            :   'Bool';
CHAR            :   'Character';
VAR             :   'var';
LET             :   'let';
FUNC            :   'func';
COLON           :   ':';
SEMI_COLON      :   ';';
PLUS            :   '+';
MINUS           :   '-';
MULTI           :   '*';
DIV             :   '/';
MOD             :   '%';
AND             :   '&&';
OR              :   '||';
NOT             :   '!';
LT              :   '<';
GT              :   '>';
LTE             :   '<=';
GTE             :   '>=';
ASSIGN          :   '=';
EQUAL           :   '==';
NOT_EQUAL       :   '!=';
SB_OPEN         :   '[';
SB_CLOSE        :   ']';
OPEN_CB         :   '{';
CLOSE_CB        :   '}';
OPEN_PAREN      :   '(';
CLOSE_PAREN     :   ')';
OPT             :   '?';
OP_DOT          :   '.';
ARROW           :   '->';
ELIP            :   '...';
IF              :   'if';
ELSE            :   'else';
SWITCH          :   'switch';
CASE            :   'case';
BREAK           :   'break';
WHILE           :   'while';
FOR             :   'for';
PRINT           :   'print';
STRUCT          :   'struct';
INT_LIT         :   '0'|DIGIT DIGIT*;
FLOAT_LIT       :   DIGIT+'.'DIGIT+;
CHAR_LIT        :   '\''(CHARACTER|ESCAPE_CHAR)'\'';
BOOL_LIT        :   'true'|'false';
STRING_LIT      :   '"'(~[\\"\r\n]|ESCAPE_CHAR)*'"';
NIL_LIT         :   'nil';
ID              :   [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
LINE_COMMENT    :   '//'.*?'\r'?'\n' -> skip;
COMMENT         :   '/*'.*?'*/' -> skip;
WS              :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;

fragment
DIGIT           :   [0-9];
fragment
CHARACTER       :   [\u0032-\u0033\u0035-\u0091\u0093-\u0126];
fragment
ESCAPE_CHAR     :   '\\' [tnr"'\\];
```

My question is about how to recognize the escape sequences for further processing, at the moment what I have is the following:

```
CHAR_LIT        :   '\''(CHARACTER|ESCAPE_CHAR)'\'';
fragment
CHARACTER       :   [\u0032-\u0033\u0035-\u0091\u0093-\u0126];
fragment
ESCAPE_CHAR     :   '\\' [tnr"'\\];
```

With this I am able to recognize most printable ASCII characters and basic escape sequences, but I am having conflicts recognizing certain characters, for example, for every instruction below:

```
print('+')

print('_')

print('*')

print('%')
```

produces the following output:

line 1:6 token recognition error at: ''+'
line 1:8 token recognition error at: '')'
line 1:10 mismatched input ';' expecting {INT_LIT, FLOAT_LIT, CHAR_LIT, BOOL_LIT
, STRING_LIT, 'nil', ID, '-', '!', '('}

And this seems to happen with almost all the symbols that I have defined in the lexer, +, -, *, /, %, &, |, etc.

However I can't figure out why the error occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Terrible error, the values within the range are hexadecimal values, I had put the decimal value. For example, for lowercase letters the range would be

```
[\u0061-\u007A]
```